# real rank in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ranking

I do a simple SQL-Query:

```
SELECT `name`, `likes`
FROM `social`
WHERE `month` = '2015-01'
ORDER BY `likes` DESC
```

then I add a "Rank" wich is an intenger with ++

```
$data = array();
$rank = 0;
while ($table_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table)) {
    $rank++;
    $data[$table_row['name']] = $table_row;
    $data[$table_row['name']]['rank'] = $rank;
}
```

The result is left and what I want on the right side

```
+------+------+-------+    +------+------+-------+
| rank | name | likes |    | rank | name | likes |
+------+------+-------+    +------+------+-------+
|    1 | foo  |   123 |    |    1 | foo  |   123 |
|    2 | mfoo |    33 |    |    2 | mfoo |    33 |
|    3 | xfoo |    33 |    |    2 | xfoo |    33 |
|    4 | yfoo |    30 |    |    4 | yfoo |    30 |
|    5 | zfoo |    29 |    |    5 | zfoo |    29 |
+------+------+-------+    +------+------+-------+
```

how do I get the right side table? is there a way to solve it in the query?

***EDIT:***

There I am standing now:

```
select IF(@likes=s.likes, @rownum, @rownum:=@rownum+1) rank2, 
    s.domain_name, s.likes,
    (@likes:=s.likes) dummy 
from social s, 
    (SELECT @rownum:=0) x, 
    (SELECT @likes:=0) y 
    WHERE `month` = '2015-01'
order by likes desc
```

but the rank is not 100% correct because I want to skip a rank instead of counting through

Comment: Providing tale with some sample data would help, also using mysql query you can achieve the rank directly.

Comment: @James think of it more as "place" than "rank", like first place, second place, etc.  Equal ranks should mean a "tie" for rank.

Comment: @DigitalChris I totally agree with you, so James think about something like a scoreboard.

Comment: @James whatever has the most likes is rank 1, second most is rank 2, etc.

Comment: Here is a way to do it in sql: http://jimmod.com/blog/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/  look at the second half of the post.

Comment: @James in that case i have an `ORDER BY likes DESC ` wich give me first the one with the most likes => rank 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this... rank should be the same for all rows with the same number of likes

```
$data = array();
$rank = 0;
$last_likes =0;
while ($table_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table)) {
    if ($last_likes != $row['likes']) {
      $rank++;
    }
    $data[$table_row['name']] = $table_row;
    $data[$table_row['name']]['rank'] = $rank;
}
```

Comment: May be its better to do `if ($last_likes != $row['likes'])` ? In case order changes....

Answer (score 0):

I see what's happening here. 
I dont know about best practices but I'd probably do something like this myself:

```
$data = array();
$rank = 0;
$lastlike = 1;
$currentlike = 0;
$i = 0;
while ($table_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table)) {

    $name = $table_row['name'];
    $currentlike = $table_row['likes'];
    if ($currentlike != $lastlike) $rank++;
    $data[$i] = array('rank'=>$rank,'name'=>$name,'likes'=>$currentlike);
    $lastlike = $currentlike;
    $i++;
}
```

I've not checked it but you're welcome to try it out and see.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with SQL or with PHP (you can test to know which one is the faster).

Note : this 2 solutions will give you a rank which start at 0.

**SQL :**

```
SELECT
    `name`,
    `likes`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `social` AS S2 WHERE S1.likes > S2.likes) AS `rank_2`
FROM `social` AS S1
WHERE `month` = '2015-01'
ORDER BY `likes` DESC
```

**PHP :**

```
$data = array();
$rank = 0;
$likes_pre = -1;
while ($table_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table)) {

    $likes_cur = $table_row['likes'];

    if ($likes_pre > $likes_cur) {
        $rank++;
    }

    $data[$table_row['name']] = $table_row;
    $data[$table_row['name']]['rank'] = $rank;

    $likes_pre = $likes_cur;
}
```

Not tested, but it should work.